# Cambiar el label de form.as_p

Tags: python, django

Hay alguna forma de cambiar los label de un form.as_p?

Tengo los valores en ingles, y quiero que en la pagina se muestre en español. Que en vez de *title* pueda poner *titulo*.

Gracias!

Comment: Puedes crear el elemento manualmente: [Rendering fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una de las formas de cambiar el label del form es esta:

```
username = forms.CharField(
    min_length=4,
    max_length=50,
    label='Nombre de usuario'
)
```

Usando el parametro label

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
 year = forms.ChoiceField(label="Año", choices=[(x, x) for x in range(actual_date - 5, actual_date + 1)],
                         initial=(actual_date, actual_date))
```

aunque te sugiero que manejes el texto que vizualizar'a el usuario de forma dinamica, ejemplo:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _


year = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("Year"), choices=[(x, x) for x in range(actual_date - 5, actual_date + 1)],
                         initial=(actual_date, actual_date))
```